# Warning: array_intersect(): Argument #2 is not an array in C:\wamp\www\#\#.php on line 41

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

When I pass `latitude` and `longitude` in negative value I am receiving this error. It works right when I passed positive value. Need a solution for it.

Error:

```
1.Warning: array_intersect(): Argument #2 is not an array in C:\wamp\www\#\#.php on line 41
2.Warning: array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in C:\wamp\www\#\#.php on line 42


$aaa=0;
$e=0;
$s=0;
$query1=mysql_query("select * from user_details where username!='$a' and availablestatus='1' and status='1'");
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query1))
    {
        $q[$e++]=$row['id'];
        $m=$row['username'];
        $k=$row['latitude'];
        $l=$row['longitude'];
        $aa[$aaa++]=1609.344 * 60 * 1.1515 * (180 / pi()) * acos(sin($i * pi() / 180) * sin($k * pi() / 180) + cos($i * pi() / 180) * cos($k * pi() / 180) * cos(($j - $l) * pi() / 180));

    }
    $res=array_combine($q,$aa);
    foreach($res as $val)
    {
        if($val>='0' && $val<='10000')
        {
            $ah[$s++]=$val;
        }
    }
    $rs=array_intersect($res,$ah);
    $rs1=array_keys($rs);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is  `if($val>='0' && $val<='10000')` is only allowing for positive values.

If this is intended behaviour then define `$ah=array();` before `foreach($res as $val)`

Comment: thanks scoota269... in $aa[$aaa++] am calculating distance value....i need to check within 10km... it its negative value... what i need to change in                                                    if($val>='0' && $val<='10000')
        {
            $ah[$s++]=$val;
        }